# Performance em objetos Javascript

Tags: javascript, orientação-a-objetos

Através de qual meio se obtêm a melhor performance de objetos Javascript.

```
var Objeto = { 
    propriedade:'valorPropriedade',
    init:function() {
       //Inicia Objetos  
    }
}
var obj = Objeto.init();
```

ou:

```
function Objeto() {
   this.propriedade = 'valorPropriedade';
   this.init = function(){
        //Função para iniciar o Objeto
   }
}

var obj = new Objeto();
obj.init();
```

Comment: Performance de criação do objeto ou de uso? E por que você está preocupado com isso, está tendo problemas com performance? Repare ainda que os códigos não são equivalentes: o que no primeiro é `Objeto`, no segundo é `obj`.

Comment: Editarei o código da pergunta. Estou desenvolvendo um Single Page Application, do lado do servidor tem um NodeJS e o consumo de algumas coisas bem pesadas. Preciso de rapidez, perceptível ao usuário em todas as pontas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A primeira opção com certeza](http://jsperf.com/construtorouiniciador). Quando você cria uma função construtora e cria um objeto através de `new`, você está criando uma cadeia de protótipos. Ou seja, todo objeto do tipo `Objeto` possui uma propriedade `[[prototype]]` (não é visível a partir do código JavaScript, apenas indiretamente via [`Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)) que, no caso, é um `Object` comum (porque você não atribuiu explicitamente o `Objeto.prototype`).

```
Objeto --> Object --> Object.prototype --> null
```

Quando você não tem uma classe `Objeto`, apenas um literal, seu objeto é do tipo simples `Object`, de modo que essa cadeia longa não existe.

```
Object --> Object.prototype --> null
```

Isso reduz todas as operações que o JavaScript tem de fazer no seu objeto em 1 nível. Na prática, não deve fazer muita diferença, mas se você quiser espremer cada ciclo da CPU (acho bobagem, na minha opinião, mas é uma escolha sua) então essa opção será mais rápida. Obs.: no teste que linkei acima a performance é **muitíssimo** diferente, mas é porque o código não faz nada de útil. À medida que o programa crescer, essa diferença deve se tornar menor, ou mesmo negligível.

**Atualização:** como apontado por @bfavaretto, a diferença de performance se dá na maior parte pela chamada extra do construtor. Se seu código fará isso com frequência (criar novos objetos) então a solução que não usa construtor deve ser mais rápida. Entretanto, pouco pode-se dizer do uso dos objetos criados de uma ou de outra maneira (pelo menos, não a partir desse teste).

Comment: Eu acho que a grande diferença na hora de criar o objeto é que `new Ctor` envolve uma chamada de função, o que implica a criação de um novo ambiente lexical etc. Em relação ao uso, você tem razão, o nível a mais na cadeia de protótipo deve causar um overhead quando se acessa uma propriedade ou método herdado.

Comment: @bfavaretto Bem observado! Atualizei os testes isolando a criação do objeto da chamada do `init`, e os testes variaram de "quase igual" (no Firefox) para "`Objeto` muito melhor" (no Chrome). Imagino que o V8 deve fazer alguma otimização no caso de "classes", não sei... De qualquer forma, um código trivial assim é quase impossível se tirar alguma conclusão definitiva - nem tem qualquer relação com a performance da aplicação no todo.

Comment: Realmente inesperada essa diferença nos testes que você adicionou. Eu esperava que a chamada de `init` tivesse a mesma performance nos dois casos. Nem consigo imaginar que tipo de otimização o V8 está fazendo!

Comment: Mais testes legais: http://jsperf.com/construtor-ou-iniciador/2

Comment: Não resisti e perguntei o porquê no SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22057579/why-is-calling-a-method-on-an-object-literal-slower-on-v8

Comment: @bfavaretto Li a pergunta que você fez, as respostas e o [link do comentário](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#prop_access). Muito interessante mesmo, no fim das contas a performance vai ser **o oposto** do que minha resposta e o teste simples apontaram (no V8 pelo menos - o que atende ao OP, já que ele pretende usar node.js). Se quiser postar seus achados como resposta, vá em frente, caso contrário amanhã à noite eu atualizo a minha.

Comment: Excelente pesquisa e muito bom ver esses materiais sendo construídos em português, continuarei seguindo ambas as discussões, acho muito proveitoso, principalmente para a aplicação dos conceitos levantados.