# Qual a diferença entre declarar uma matriz com "array()" e "[]" em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, array, declaração-de-variável

Em JavaScript podemos declarar uma matriz de duas maneiras:

```
var matriz = new Array();
```

e

```
var matriz = [];
```

Qual é a diferença entre as duas e que consequências dai advêm?

---

<sup>Esta pergunta está a ser colocada com o propósito de documentar em Português a sua versão original que pode ser vista no SOEN: [What’s the difference between “Array()” and “[]” while declaring a JavaScript array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/931872/352449)</sup>

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ambas as formas [produzem o mesmo resultado](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Creating_an_Array) (ao contrário de `String`, por exemplo, em que [há diferença](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#String_Object) entre o literal `"foo"` e o objeto `new String("foo")`). Em JavaScript, arrays não são "especiais" de nenhuma forma - apenas objetos com um parâmetro `length`. Mesmo os índices são idênticos ao de um objeto comum, texuais (ex.: `arr[0]` é o mesmo que `arr["0"]`).

[Esta seção da especificação ECMAScript](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.4) descreve o literal para arrays como um "iniciador de objetos" (*object initializer*), com o mesmo efeito na prática que a criação via `new Array`. Já [esta outra seção](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.1) determina que uma chamada ao construtor na forma de função (i.e. sem o `new`, apenas `Array(params)`) tem o mesmo efeito que sua chamada na forma de construtor. De modo que as três formas são de fato equivalentes:

```
var arr = new Array(element0, element1, ..., elementN);
var arr = Array(element0, element1, ..., elementN);
var arr = [element0, element1, ..., elementN];
```

Como apontado nas respostas à pergunta similar no SOEN, há alguns detalhes a se considerar:

- A criação de um array via literal permite no máximo que você especifique os elementos iniciais. A criação via construtor permite que se especifique somente o `length` do array, e mais nada (chamando-se o construtor com um único argumento numérico). Isso é contra-intuitivo e pode causar erros inesperados:

  ```
  var a = new Array(1);   // length:1 (e mais nada)
  var b = new Array(1,2); // length:2, 0:1, 1:2
  var c = new Array('1'); // length:1, 0:'1'
  ```

  [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/931875/520779)

  **Nota:** Se usado dessa forma, o número deve necessariamente ser inteiro. Essa chamada por exemplo lançará uma exceção:

  ```
  var d = new Array(1.5); // RangeError: Invalid array length
  ```
- Pode-se **redefinir** o construtor `Array` como quiser (embora aí já deixe de ser o `Array` nativo), de modo a customizar a criação de novos arrays. Quando se faz isso, a criação via literal não é modificada:

  ```
  var proto = Array.prototype;
  function Array() {
      this.is = 'SPARTA';
  }
  Array.prototype = proto;

  var a = new Array();
  var b = [];

  alert(a.is);  // => 'SPARTA'
  alert(b.is);  // => undefined
  ```

  O mesmo ocorre caso se tente substituir `window.Array` (i.e. modificar o objeto global, que no caso dos browsers é `window`), a criação via literal não é afetada. Por essas razões, a performance da criação via literal deve ser ligeiramente maior, haja vista que não há a verificação do contexto em busca da variável `Array`, etc.

  [Fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1273936/520779)

  **Nota:** como apontado por @bfavaretto nos comentários, redefinir objetos nativos do JavaScript é uma péssima prática (agravado pelo fato de que não é exatamente uma redefinição que se está fazendo, e sim criando um objeto não relacionado, apenas com o mesmo nome, i.e. *shadowing*).

Embora o exposto acima esteja em conformidade com a especificação, implementações particulares podem fazer otimizações em um ou outro caso. Como observado [nessa pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7521/215), às vezes duas construções que à primeira vista parecem equivalentes possuem performance radicalmente diferentes na prática. O mesmo vale para usar um `Array` ou simplesmente um "array-like" (i.e. um objeto comum com um campo `length`).

Na ausência de informações específicas, o que resta é testar e experimentar (como na [resposta do @Miguel Angelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8037/215), onde ele confirma que os `prototype`s são iguais; o mesmo pode ser observado usando `Object.getPrototypeOf` nos dois arrays e comparando-os). Entretanto, nesse caso a especificação é clara, creio que não vai haver nenhuma "surpresa"...

Comment: +1, eu estava para completar minha resposta com esse caso da redefinição do construtor `Array`. Isso realmente faz diferença – **e vale lembrar que é uma péssima prática**.

Comment: @bfavaretto tem razão, adicionei uma nota quanto a isso. Pessoalmente, nunca me ocorreria fazer tal coisa (no máximo, redefiniria `window.Array` se tivesse uma necessidade extrema - se bem que nem isso afeta os literais...), apenas "tirei a ideia" das respostas no SOEN. Não quero que ninguém tire essa ideia errada da minha resposta :P

Answer (score 15):

No código que você usou como exemplo, não há diferença. Porém, o construtor `Array` pode receber parâmetros, e dependendo do que for passado ele se comporta de maneira diferente.

Por exemplo, se você passar qualquer valor que não seja numérico inteiro, estará criando uma array contendo o que foi passado:

```
var a = new Array('um', 'dois');
console.log(a); // ["um", "dois"]
```

Se você passar somente um parâmetro, e se ele for um valor numérico inteiro, estará criando uma array com comprimento (propriedade `length`) igual ao valor passado:

```
var b = new Array(4);
console.log(b); // [undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined]
```

Note que na verdade a array *não* está preenchida com `undefined`; a saída que vemos no console é consequência de como funciona o método `toString` dela. É possível demonstrar isso, por exemplo executando `b.hasOwnProperty("0")`, cujo resultado é `false`.

---

**Nota 1**: o construtor `Array` pode ser utilizado com ou sem `new`, e o resultado será o mesmo.

---

**Nota 2**: caso o construtor `Array` seja redefinido, arrays criadas com a forma literal `[]` não são afetadas. E arrays criadas com o "falso" construtor não serão arrays de verdade.

Answer (score 4):

A diferença deve ser mínima (i.e. apenas no código pelo que posso ver). Tive a ideia de testar com o `prototype` do Array, antes de instanciar tanto usando a forma literal, quanto como usado o construtor com o operador `new`... a propriedade adicional que coloquei no protótipo foi parar em ambas as instâncias:

```js
Array.prototype.myVar = 10928;

var a = [];
var b = new Array();

alert("a.myVar = " + a.myVar + "; b.myVar = " + b.myVar );
```

Answer (score 0):

Creio que a única diferença é o modo de declaração, a `var matriz` irá ser compreendida como sendo um `Array` ou não, pelo menos semânticamente.

Answer (score 0):

**Não há nenhuma diferença, ambas são formas igualmente aceitas para a construção da Array.**

É idêntico a construção de uma função que pode ser feita tanto da forma:

```
function sum(x,y) = {
   var x = 1;
   var y = 1;
   console.log(x+y);
}
```

ou:

```
var sum = new function(x,y) = {
   var x = 1;
   var y = 1;
   console.log(x+y);
}
```

Ambas retornam a mesma exata função.

Answer (score 0):

Apenas açúcar sintático. Utilizando "[]" é a forma literal da instanciação via função construtora (Array).