# Como construir Array de Objetos

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, objetos

Estou tentando construir um Array de Objetos em JavaScript, mas o resultado não é o esperado. 
Era assim que eu gostaria que ficasse:
[image: correto]

Mas é assim que está ficando:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o codigo que estou usando:

```
var wo = new Array();
while ( listItemEnumerator.moveNext() ) 
        {
            var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
            wo.push( { ID: oListItem.get_id(), Status: oListItem.get_item( 'Status' ) } );
        }
```

Preciso que o Array de Objetos seja construído dentro do `WHILE`
Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Não entendi qual a diferença entre o resultado esperado e o obtido. Poderia explicar melhor? Sugestão: em vez de fazer `console.log(wo)`, faça `console.log(JSON.stringify(wo))` e veja qual a diferença real entre o esperado e o obtido. Pois à primeira vista, seu código parece correto... P.S. [Pergunta relacionada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8035/215)

Comment: parece q ele esta construindo um Objeto de Objetos ao invés de Array de Objetos.. vou testar seu comando

Comment: @Thiago, seu array parece esta correto, confira novamente seu resultado.

Comment: @Thiago Ambas as capturas de tela mostram arrays. Em um caso, o array é muito grande, então ele foi representado por `Array[32]`. No outro, ele cabe na linha, então ele foi representado por `[Object,Object,Object...]`. Mas ambos são arrays mesmo, internamente não há diferença alguma. A propósito, se você não tiver familiaridade com literais de arrays, sugiro dar uma lida na pergunta relacionada.

Comment: realmente não tem diferença mesmo, nos dois jeitos esta criando um array de objetos...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não existe diferença entre os dois, a diferença está na forma como o console do Chrome está mostrando ele apenas.

E não é pelo tamanho do Array que ele faz isso, pelos testes que fiz aqui ele muda a forma como ele exibe o array se na hora que o `console.log` for chamado as ferramentas de desenvolvimento estiverem abertas.

Testando aqui na versão 36 do Chrome, se estou com as ferramentas de desenvolvimento abertas e então abro a página com o Script o resultado é o segundo, porém se deixo as ferramentas de desenvolvimento fechadas, abro a página e só após ela executar o script eu abrir as ferramentas de desenvolvimento então o resultado será o primeiro.

E só uma nota, o recomendado na hora de se criar um array no javascript é usar da seguinte forma

```
var wo = [];
```

Você pode ler um pouco mais do porque disso no site do [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), na parte "Avoid new Array()"