# Quando usar a notação literal de array em JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Passei a usar o [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) nos meus projetos, juntamente com o [Sublime Linter](http://www.sublimelinter.com/en/latest/) (o que, aliás, recomento). Após fazer o *setup* inicial, deparei-me com o seguinte alerta:

> The array literal notation is preferable

em uma declaração do tipo:

```
var myArray = new Array();
```

Claro que isto é facilmente contornado com:

```
var myArray = [];
```

Lembro-me de já ter lido alguns relatos a cerca da performance de uma ou outra notação, mas nada muito concreto. Li também que, no ES6, ambas teriam exatamente a mesma funcionalidade. A pergunta (ou as perguntas) é:

- Qual é a diferença entre as notações?
- Existe, em termos práticos, uma diferença de performance entre elas?
- Existem *edge cases* onde apenas uma das duas seria a correta?
- Qual usar, afinal de contas?

Comment: Seria isso? [Qual a diferença entre declarar uma matriz com “array” e “\[\]” em JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8035/91)

Comment: @rray possívelmente. e olha que eu procurei antes de abrir a pergunta