# Exibir valor de um indice array em um alert

Tags: javascript

Olá

Como eu faço para exibir um valor de um indice array em um alert em javascript?

```js
a[i] = "Carro";
alert(a[i]);
```

Obrigado

Comment: pra mim não ficou claro, você quer exibir o valor de `i`, "carro" ou outra coisa?

Comment: Isso não estará dentro de um `for` ? Como está o código todo ? É só isso?

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que queres fazer? Dá um exemplo do que esperavas que desse.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre declarar uma matriz com "array()" e "\[\]" em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8035/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-declarar-uma-matriz-com-array-e-em-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aparentemente sua idéia de como exibir o valor não está errada, basta corrigir a sintaxe.

```js
var a = [];
a[0] = 'Carro';
alert(a[0]);
```

Em caso do array estar dentro de um laço:

```js
    var a = [];
    a[0] = 'Carro';
    
    for (i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
      alert(a[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

O que você está tentando fazer é usar a variavel `i` para declarar o indice, porem, não está dentro de um `for`

```js
let arr = ["Carro", "Avião", "Moto"]

// Aqui você faz passando o indice manualmente
alert(arr[0])

// Nesse caso você usa o I, ele irá percorrer todos os indices
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pergunta não muito clara.

Em primeiro lugar, não é necessário dar essa volta

```
var a = [];
a[0] = 'Carro';
alert(a[0]);
```

para exibir esse alerta basta `alert("Carro");`

Do jeito que está feita a pergunta (e subentendo dentro de um loop) teria esse retorno:

```js
var a = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      //a cada iteração o valor do elemento é alterado para Carro
      a[i] = "Carro";
      console.log(a[i]);
    }
```

**O mais provável é que você esteja querendo o abaixo**

Dentro de um loop para exibir os elementos do array

```js
var a = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      console.log(a[i]);
    }
```