# Qual a diferença nas declarações com [] e {} em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var a=[]
var b={}
```

Qual a diferença nas declarações com `[]` e `{}` em JavaScript? E em qual contexto é melhor utilização cada?

Pergunta em inglês: [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33514915)

Comment: Ficou com alguma dúvida em relação a isso ou só achou interessante trazer a pergunta para cá também?

Comment: Duvidas com relação ao contexto da utilização e também ter uma resposta em pt. @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual a diferença entre declarar uma matriz com "array()" e "\[\]" em JavaScript?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8035/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-declarar-uma-matriz-com-array-e-em-javascript)

Comment: @ThiagoLoureiro a dúvida dele e2 diferente e importante para sanar dúvidas de outras pessoas ao meu entendimento

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basicamente utiliza-se as chaves {} quando se pretende declarar um objeto. Irei dar um exemplo criando um objeto com sub valores ou melhor dizendo, definindo valores dentro dese objeto

```
var carro = {
marca: "Ford",
modelo: "Ka",
   getDetalhes: function () {
      return this.marca + ' - ' + this.modelo;
   }
}
```

Também podemos envolver em chaves os objetos criados dentro de uma function

```
function Carro(){
   var Marca = "Sem marca";
   var Modelo = "Sem modelo";
}
```

Já na utilização de colchetes [], você estará criando / indicando um array.  Como irei mostrar abaixo

```
var a = [];
    a[0] = "Bob";
    a[1] = "Marley";
    a[2] = "Reggae";
```

Ou seja, indiquei que a variável é um array, onde o primeiro valor deste array é uma string com titulo Bob, a segunda chave do array é uma string de titulo Marley e a terceira chave deste array indica o valor com titulo Reggae

Também pode indicar um array desta forma como irei mostrar abaixo

```
var a =  ["Bob", "Marley", "Reggae"];
```

Lembrando que também pode-se criar um array em JavaScript com (), desta forma como irei indicar abaixo

```
var a = new Array( "Bob", "Marley", "Reggae");
```

Ou até mesmo desta forma que seria equivalente as outras duas

```
var a = Array("Bob", "Marley", "Reggae");
```

Answer (score 3):

A diferença é que `{}` pode ser usado para criar um objeto com sub-valores e `[]` para criar um objeto array.

Exemplo de objeto com `{}`:

```
var cliente = {
    usuario1: {
        nome: "João",
        idade: "23",
        estado: "SP"
    },
    usuario2: {
        nome: "Maria",
        idade: "30",
        estado: "RJ"
    }
}
```

Então você consegue acessar a informação que quiser dentro do objeto chamando hierarquicamente pelo nome das variáveis dentro dele:

```
console.log(cliente.usuario1.nome); // retorna o "nome" do "usuario1", "João"
```

Já com os `[]`, você irá criar uma array simples, onde cada item tem um valor e um índice, que começa com `0`:

```
var array = ['joao','maria'];
console.log(array[0]); // retorna o valor do índice 0, "joao"
```

Mas você também pode mesclar as duas coisas. Abaixo uma array com informações separadas em cada índice:

```
var array = [{nome:'joao', cidade: 'RJ'}, {nome:'maria', cidade: 'SP'}];
console.log(array[1].cidade); // retorna "SP"
```

---

A vantagem de usar uma coisa ou outra vai depender muito da sua aplicação. Se você quer apenas armazenar valores simples, separados por índices, use array `[]`. Se quiser armazenar valores que contenham sub-valores em um objeto específico, use `{}`.