# Como funciona o retorno undefined?

Tags: javascript

Quando é declarado uma variável, mas a mesma não possui nenhum valor atribuido a ela, teoricamente ela não possui nenhum dado, mas ela existe na memória e está pronta para ser utilizada:

```
let myVariable;
```

Mas ao tentar utilizar está mesma variável como, por exemplo, imprimir o valor dela no console é rotornado o valor `undefined`:

```js
let myVariable;

console.log(myVariable);
```

Este valor que foi retornado que é `undefined` é realmente o valor da variável e no qual a partir daqui o valor desta variável é `undefined`? ou apenas é um valor para informar que a variável está com o valor indefinido, mas continuar com o valor "nada" na memória do computador?

Isso também acontece, por exemplo, com arrays quando, você utiliza o construtor `Array()` com um parâmetro númerico inteiro e positivo especificado no qual se for definido, por exemplo, o valor `10` terá 10 posições com valores vazios e no qual se for tentado acessá-lo também retornará `undefined`:

```js
let myArray  = new Array(10);

console.log(`Posições: ${myArray.length}`);

for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i ++) {
    console.log(`Valor da posição ${i}: ${myArray[i]}`);
}
```

Em uma resposta do [bfavaretto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8035/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-declarar-uma-matriz-com-array-e-em-javascript#answer-8046) ele menciona que:

> Note que na verdade a array não está preenchida com undefined; a saída que vemos no console é consequência de como funciona o método toString dela.

Nesta menção ele explica o do porque estar retornando `undefined`, mas eu não entendi o que ele quis dizer.

Este retorno ele existe apenas para especificar ou confimar que o valor de retorno é `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Antes de mais nada, vale lembrar que `Undefined` é um dos tipos definidos pela linguagem (assim como `String`, `Number`, `Boolean`, etc). [E a especificação diz o seguinte](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-undefined-type):

> *The Undefined type has exactly one value, called undefined. Any variable that has not been assigned a value has the value undefined.*

Ou seja, o tipo `Undefined` possui apenas um valor, que é [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/undefined). E qualquer variável a qual não foi atribuído um valor, tem o valor `undefined`.

Ou seja, ao fazer apenas `let variavel;`, a variável possui o valor `undefined` (e só para deixar mais confuso, ainda existe uma [propriedade do objeto global chamada `undefined`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-undefined) cujo valor é - adivinhe - `undefined`).

---

Quanto a arrays, é um pouco mais complicado. Segue explicação baseada [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44471705).

O construtor `Array(n)`, quando chamado com apenas um argumento, e este argumento é um número inteiro, retorna um array cujo tamanho (ou seja, cujo valor da propriedade `length`) é este número.

Mas ao tentar acessar qualquer um dos elementos do mesmo, o retorno é `undefined`:

```js
let x = Array(2);
console.log(x.length); // 2
console.log(x[0], x[1]); // undefined, undefined
console.log(x);
```

Obs: na última linha podem haver divergências quanto à saída. Rodando no snippet do site, eu obtive `[undefined, undefined]`, mas próprio console do Chrome, o retorno foi `[empty x 2]` e no Node foi `[ <2 empty items> ]`.

O que acontece é que, apesar de parecer, `Array(2)` não é a mesma coisa que `[undefined, undefined]`. Por exemplo, se mapearmos cada elemento do array para algum valor qualquer, usando `map`:

```js
console.log([undefined, undefined].map(e => 1));  // [1, 1]
console.log(new Array(2).map(e => 1));
```

Sobre a última linha, novamente houve a divergência: no snippet do site, a saída foi `[undefined, undefined]` e no Chrome e Node a saída foi respectivamente `[empty x 2]` e `[ <2 empty items> ]`.

Enfim, segundo a [especificação](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array-len), o construtor `Array(tamanho)` só cria um array cujo valor da propriedade `length` é o tamanho informado, e só. Nenhum elemento de fato foi criado dentro dele.

Por isso ao percorrê-lo com `map` o resultado continua sendo "2 empty items", pois a [especificação](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.map) diz que `map` verifica se a propriedade do array (o índice, no caso) existe. Mas o array criado com `Array(tamanho)` não possui essas propriedades:

```js
function verificarIndices(array) {
    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        console.log(`tem ${i}? ${array.hasOwnProperty(i)}`);
    }
}

console.log('array de undefined');
verificarIndices([undefined, undefined]); // imprime "true" para os índices
console.log('Array(2)');
verificarIndices(Array(2));  // imprime "false" para os índices

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames([undefined, undefined]));  // ['0', '1', 'length']
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Array(2))); // ['length']
```

O que nos leva a concluir que o array não possui elementos, e `undefined` é apenas um valor que é retornado quando um elemento não existe. Afinal, é isso que ocorre quando acessamos um índice que não existe:

```js
let x = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(x[999]); // undefined
```

Por fim, outra forma de ver que o array criado por `Array(n)` não tem índices (e portanto podemos concluir que não tem os respectivos elementos):

```js
console.log('percorrendo [undefined, undefined]');
for (let i in [undefined, undefined])
    console.log(i); // imprime 0 e 1

console.log('percorrendo Array(2)');
for (let i in Array(2))
    console.log(i); // não imprime nada

console.log('--------');
console.log(Object.keys([undefined, undefined])); // [ '0', '1' ]
console.log(Object.keys(Array(2))); // []
```

---

E quanto ao comentário sobre `toString`, [a especificação diz que `toString` chama internamente o método `join`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.tostring) sem argumentos. E quando [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) é chamado sem argumentos, a [especificação diz](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.join) que é usada uma vírgula como separador. O algoritmo também diz que, se o elemento for `undefined` ou `null`, é usada a string vazia no lugar. E como já vimos que o acesso aos elementos não existentes de `Array(2)` retorna `undefined`, o resultado de `toString` será um monte de vírgulas (para ser mais preciso, em um array de tamanho N, serão N - 1 vírgulas).

Comment: Então para variáveis o `undefined` existe, mas para arrays só no momento em que o mesmo é acessado?

Comment: @felipecardozo Na verdade acredito que para objetos em geral, ao tentar acessar uma propriedade que não existe, deve ter um "if (não existe) retorna undefined" (e os índices de um array no fundo são propriedades do mesmo). Eu não achei esse trecho da especificação mas tenho quase certeza que deve ter - se eu encontrar, atualizo a resposta

Comment: beleza :), valeu!

Comment: @felipecardozo Não encontrei o trecho da especificação, mas incluí outro exemplo na resposta. Talvez agora fique mais claro que `Array(2)` de fato só seta o tamanho (`length`) mas não cria os elementos

Comment: Valeu, colega! pelo esforço ficou mais claro para mim.

Answer (score 2):

`undefined` é um valor, assim como `null` também é um valor. O código precisa saber o que é `undefined` para poder trabalhar com ele.

Uma variável não inicializada é apenas uma região da memória que foi adquirida, mas ainda contém o conteúdo que estava alocado nessa região anteriormente. Não tem como o seu processo saber que esse lixo representa um valor não inicializado, a menos que ele inicialize essa variável com um valor que representa não estar inicializada (isso faz sentido?)

`undefined` assim como `null` são ponteiros que apontam para uma região de memória que não deveria ser acessada. Qual região? Geralmente 0x00000000 ou 0x00000001, mas isso é detalhe de implementação, e não cabe a linguagem definir isso.

Quando você declara uma variável mas não a inicializa, o próprio processo irá inicializa-la com o valor `undefined`. A variável foi de fato inicializada, com um valor que representa não ter sido inicializada pelo programador.

Por outro lado, quando você acessa uma propriedade inválida de um objeto ou de um array, por regra da linguagem JavaScript, você receberá `undefined`, mas isso não significa que essa região de memória contém o valor `undefined`, isso é apenas o retorno definido pela regra... o que pode ser um pouco ambíguo.

```js
var arr = new Array(2);
arr[0] = undefined;

console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[1]);
```

No exemplo acima por exemplo, o array já foi inicializado com a capacidade 2, a propriedade `0` contém o valor `undefined`, e a propriedade `1` não existe, o que resulta em `undefined`. Se houver a necessidade de diferenciar um valor `undefined` e uma propriedade não existente, você precisará recorrer ao operador `in`:

```js
var arr = new Array(2);
arr[0] = undefined;

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (i in arr) console.log(`A propriedade ${i} existe, e seu valor é ${arr[i]}`);
  else console.log(`A propriedade ${i} não existe, e portanto é retornado ${arr[i]}`);
}
```