# Como os loops "for in, for of, foreach" percorrem o array?

Tags: javascript, loop, for

Sempre usei o loop `for` no qual o mesmo diferencia um pouco dos loops mencionados, mas a questão é de como estes loops percorrem o array como, por exemplo, o loop `for` normalmente segue estes passos para percorrer o array:

```js
for (let i = 0; i <= 10; i ++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

1. Inicie a variável `i` com o valor `0`.
2. O valor da variável `i` é menor ou igual a `10`?

   - Se for `true` execute o bloco de código.

     - No final incremente `1` na variável `i`.
     - Volte para o passo 2.
   - Se for `false`, pare o loop e segue o fluxo de execução normal do código.

Agora, já nos *loops* mencionados no título da pergunta como eles funcionariam?

Comment: Felipe, faltou alguma coisas nas respostas abaixo? Pelo que entendi, elas respondem o que foi perguntado - a menos que eu tenha entendido errado, claro :-)

Answer (score 8):

O laço [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) é um padrão de projeto para repetir comandos com uma inicialização, um passo que sempre será executado em cada iteração e uma condição que determinará quando deve parar de repetir.

Algumas linguagens criaram sintaxe para permitir novos padrões de projeto que fazem coisas mais comuns, assim algumas situações podem ser demonstradas de forma mais simples e evitando certos erros, e eventualmente até conseguindo fazer alguma otimização (em outras pode haver um custo extra).

O JavaScript não tem um comando `foreach`, só uma função com esse nome e é só isso uma função que tem uma laço dentro, de forma geral não faz sentido iusá-lo, mas as pessoas adoram, é só custo sem vantagem, pelo contrário têm desvantagens.

Existe na linguagem só o [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) e o [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Diferenças que já foram explicadas em [Qual é a diferença entre o for...of e o for..in?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90352/101).

Então esses laços já pegam um objeto e varrem todos seus membros. A linguagem inicializa a variável para começar o primeiro elemento, a condição determinará quando os elementos acabaram e o passo é o que faz você ir para o próximo elemento. Dependendo do tipo de objeto a linguagem pode fazer isso de uma forma diferente para se adequar. Ele não faz diferente do que você deveria fazer na mesma situação, se você não faz igual pode ser que esteja fazendo errado.

Então

```js
var objeto = { a: 'A', b: 'B', c: 'C' };
for (var i in objeto) console.log(objeto[i]);
```

Na verdade seria mais ou menos assim:

```js
var objeto = { a: "A", b: "B", c: "C" };
var obj = Object.entries(objeto);
const it = obj.values();
let entry;
while (!(entry = it.next()).done) console.log(entry.value[1]);
```

```js
var objeto = [1, 2, 3];
for (var i of objeto) console.log(i);
```

Se transforma mais ou menos em:

```js
var objeto = [1, 2, 3];
const it = objeto.values();
let entry;
while (!(entry = it.next()).done) console.log(entry.value);
```

Pode ser que fique mais simplificado (depende de implementação):

```js
var objeto = [1, 2, 3];
let i = 0;
while (i < objeto.length) console.log(objeto[i++]);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/HowForWorks.js).

A grosso modo é isso e reforço que a forma exata de funcionamento depende de implementação, desde que siga a especificação.

Comment: O modo `while (ì < objecto.length)` só funciona array.

Answer (score 8):

## `for..in`

O [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) itera sobre as [propriedades enumeráveis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties) de um objeto, desde que as chaves sejam strings (pois as chaves também pode ser [`Symbol`'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)).

Repare que isso vale para qualquer objeto, não somente arrays. Ex:

```js
function forIn(obj) {
    for (let i in obj) {
        console.log(`${i} = ${obj[i]}`);
    }
}

// testando com array
let x = [0, 1, 2];
x[Symbol('simbolo')] = 'symbol'; // chave não é string, não é mostrada no for..in
Object.defineProperty(x, 'no', { value: 10, enumerable: false }); // não-enumerável, não é mostrada no for..in
Object.defineProperty(x, 'yes', { value: 10, enumerable: true });  // enumerável, é mostrada no for..in

// definindo propriedades nos protótipos, todos os arrays a terão
Array.prototype.bla = 'bla';
Object.prototype.all = 'all';
console.log('iterando no array');
forIn(x); // mostra 0, 1, 2, "yes", "bla" e "all"

console.log(Object.entries(x)); // mostra 0, 1, 2 e "yes" (não mostra o "bla" nem o "all")

// testando com um objeto qualquer
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    [Symbol('c')]: 3 // símbolo, não é mostrada no for..in
};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', { value: 2, enumerable: false }); // não-enumerável, não é mostrada no for..in
console.log('iterando no objeto');
forIn(obj); // mostra "a" e "all"
console.log(Object.entries(obj)); // mostra somente "a"

// testando com string
let s = 'a';
console.log('iterando na string');
forIn(s); // mostra o "all" (setado no prototype de Object) e 3 "caracteres"
console.log(Object.entries(s)); // não mostra o "all"
```

A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471073/112052) disse que fazer `for (let i in x)` seria equivalente a percorrer os elementos de `Object.entries(x)`, mas existe uma diferença: [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) não traz as propriedades setadas no protótipo do objeto (como as propriedades "bla" e "all" do exemplo acima, que foram definidas respectivamente em `Array.prototype` e `Object.prototype`). Já o `for..in` traz essas propriedades, então se você quisesse ignorá-las, teria que fazer algo do tipo:

```
for (let i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) console.log(`${i} = ${obj[i]}`);
}
```

Aí sim o "bla" e "all" seriam ignorados.

No caso da string, é mais curioso ainda. Apesar dela só ter 2 "caracteres" (a letra "a" e o emoji), são retornados 4 propriedades: o "all" (herdado de `Object.prototype`) e os 3 índices que correspondem aos seus "caracteres". Na verdade o emoji foi quebrado em 2 partes, [conforme explicado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443744/112052).

---

Outro detalhe importante, no caso de arrays, é que a [documentação diz que não é garantido que os elementos sejam retornados na ordem dos seus índices numéricos](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in) (*There is no guarantee that `for...in` will return the indexes in any particular order*). Testando no Chrome, vi que ele itera na ordem, mas isso pode não ocorrer em todas as implementações.

Outro caso em que dá diferença para um `for` tradicional é quando [criamos um "array esburacado"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/510957/112052):

```js
let x = [];
x[5] = 5;
// imprime só o 5
for(let i in x) console.log(`${i} = ${x[i]}`);

// imprime 5 vezes "undefined" antes do 5
for(let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) console.log(`${i} = ${x[i]}`);
```

De qualquer forma, um ponto importante é que o `for..in` funciona com qualquer objeto, iterando pelas propriedades enumeráveis do mesmo.

---

## `for..of`

O `for..of`, ao contrário do `for..in`, não funciona com qualquer objeto, mas somente com aqueles que são [iteráveis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol). Isso inclui strings, arrays, e objetos *array-like* (como por exemplo o [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) retornado por [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)). A [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterable_protocol) também explica como criar seu próprio tipo iterável.

Ex:

```js
function forOf(obj) {
    for (let i of obj) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}

// testando com array
let x = [0, 1, 2];
x[Symbol('simbolo')] = 'symbol';
Object.defineProperty(x, 'no', { value: 10, enumerable: false });
Object.defineProperty(x, 'yes', { value: 10, enumerable: true });

// definindo propriedades nos protótipos, todos os arrays a terão
Array.prototype.bla = 'bla';
Object.prototype.all = 'all';

forOf(x); // mostra 0, 1, 2

// com uma string
let s = 'a';
forOf(s); // mostra o "a" e o emoji

// testando com um objeto qualquer
let obj = {
    a: 1,
    [Symbol('c')]: 3
};
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'b', { value: 2, enumerable: false });
forOf(obj); // TypeError: obj is not iterable
```

Repare que agora as propriedades "extras", sejam ela enumeráveis ou não, definidas no próprio objeto ou no protótipo, são todas ignoradas.

No caso do array, somente os elementos são mostrados, pois [o iterador de um array foi definido para funcionar assim](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-createarrayiterator): começa do índice zero e vai incrementando, até chegar ao `length` do array - por isso o caso abaixo dá diferença para um `for..in`:

```js
let x = [];
x[3] = 3;
x.bla = 'bla';
x.length = 5;
// imprime só o 3 e "bla"
console.log('for..in só pega as propriedades que existem');
for(let i in x) console.log(x[i]);

// imprime 3 vezes "undefined" antes do 3, depois outro "undefined"
console.log('for..of itera por todos os índices, até o length');
for(let i of x) console.log(i);
```

Repare no caso acima: `for..in` só iterou pelas propriedades existentes (no caso, o "3" e "bla"). Já `for..of` iterou pelos índices numéricos, começando do zero e indo até `length - 1` (ou seja, tentou acessar os índices 0, 1 e 2, que como não existem, [resultam em `undefined`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/468766/112052), depois acessou o índice 3, e depois tentou acessar o índice 4 - já que o `length` é 5, então o *loop* vai até o índice 4 - que como não existe, também resulta em `undefined`).

---

No caso da string, o emoji não é mais "quebrado" e é exibido corretamente, pois o [iterador de `String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/@@iterator) garante este comportamento (ele itera sobre os code points da mesma - leia a [pergunta já indicada acima](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/443744/112052) para entender melhor).

E no caso do objeto, dá erro porque ele não é iterável (*TypeError: obj is not iterable*). Para que funcionasse com o mesmo, eu teria que definir um iterador para ele. Algo assim:

```js
let obj = {
    a: 10, b: 20
};
// iterador: retorna os valores das propriedades deste objeto
obj[Symbol.iterator] = function* () {
    for (let p in this) yield this[p];
};

for (let i of obj) console.log(i); // imprime 10 e 20
```

No caso, eu usei `for..in` internamente para iterar pelas propriedades, e fiz o iterador retornar o respectivo valor da propriedade (mas eu poderia ter usado qualquer outra lógica interna para retornar os valores que eu quisesse, retornando inclusive valores que não necessariamente estão relacionados com as propriedades do objeto). Desta forma é possível iterar neste objeto com `for..of`.

No caso dos objetos nativos que podem ser iterados com `for..of` (como arrays e strings), eles internamente já implementam seu próprio iterador. Para os demais, basta seguir a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols), que dá instruções para deixar seus objetos de acordo com os protocolos de iteração.

---

## `forEach`

Ao contrário de `for..in` e `for..of`, que são construções da linguagem, `forEach` é um método do `Array` (embora não seja exclusivo deste, pois [vários outros tipos também possuem um método similar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=forEach), como [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/forEach), [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), etc).

Uma coisa que todos têm em comum é que você deve passar uma função de *callback* que é chamada para cada um dos elementos sendo percorridos. Por exemplo, no caso de arrays, ele itera pelos índices numéricos do mesmo, e no *callback* você passa o elemento e o respectivo índice:

```js
let x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
x.forEach(function (elemento, indice) { // imprime os índices e os respectivos elementos
    console.log(`x[${indice}] = ${elemento}`);
});
```

A forma como ele funciona varia conforme o tipo. No caso de arrays, ele percorre os índices numéricos, até atingir o `length` do mesmo, mas ao contrário de `for..of`, o `forEach` verifica se o índice existe ([veja o algoritmo na especificação](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.foreach)). Daí que podemos ter situações como essa:

```js
let x = [];
x[2] = 2;
x.forEach(function (elemento, indice) { // imprime somente o 2 (os índices 0 e 1 não existem)
    console.log(`x[${indice}] = ${elemento}`);
});

x[5] = 5;
x.forEach(function (elemento, indice) { // imprime somente o 2 e o 5 (os outros índices não existem)
    console.log(`x[${indice}] = ${elemento}`);
});
```

Já outros tipos podem implementar o `forEach` de maneira diferente. Por exemplo, um `Set` não define chaves, então os seus valores acabam sendo as próprias "chaves". Em um [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) o `forEach` também itera pelas chaves não numéricas, etc. Cada tipo implementa o seu `forEach` de acordo com o que faz sentido para o seu propósito.