# Por que implementar guard-for-in em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, for, eslint

Utilizando o ESLint no meu código, ele gera erros de [guard-for-in](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/guard-for-in) em alguns for-loops, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
for (const key in params) {
    doSomething(params[key]);
}
```

Para solucionar esse erro, a documentação sugere utilizar uma condicional para verificar se a chave existe no objeto, exemplo:

```
for (const key in params) {
    if (Object.hasOwn(params, key)) {
        doSomething(params[key]);
    }
}
```

No entanto, ainda não entra na minha cabeça o porquê isso é necessário. O único motivo que eu consigo pensar é que isso possa ser útil para evitar erro ou obter um `undefined` caso alguma task em paralelo remova um item X do objeto, que seria obtido no momento exato daquela próxima iteração. No entanto, esse é um caso bem extremo, improvável e evitável.

Dito isso, quais outros motivos justificam o uso de tal verificação em um `for .. in`, uma vez que teoricamente todas as chaves da iteração devem estar contidas no objeto? É realmente necessário? Seria perigoso para o código simplesmente ignorar os erros de `guard-for-in` do ESLint?

Comment: Fecharam a minha pergunta, indicando quatro outras perguntas feitas, porém apenas na resposta do Luiz, da última indicação, é **citado** a resposta para essa pergunta. Eu acho que vale essa pergunta ser reaberta.

Comment: [Aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/471082/112052) tem um caso que faz diferença, não sei se era isso que vc quer saber

Comment: O próprio link do ESLint que você incluiu na pergunta dá a explicação: *Looping over objects with a for in loop will include properties that are inherited through the prototype chain. This behavior can lead to unexpected items in your for loop.*