# Como funciona o método map()?

Tags: javascript, array, map

Gostaria de saber como o método `.map` trabalha "atrás das cortinas".

Por exemplo, criei uma função para desenvolver uma função similar ao método `forEach` e ficou assim:

```js
const conjuntoDados = [
  20,
  15,
  10,
  5,
  30
]

function newForEach(callbackFn, thisArg, arrayIterado) {
  for (let contador = 0; contador < arrayIterado.length; contador++) {
    const elemento = arrayIterado[contador];
    const index = contador;
    const array = arrayIterado;
    callbackFn(elemento, index, array)
  }
}

newForEach((elemento, index, array) => {
  console.log(elemento)
}, null, conjuntoDados)
```

Gostaria de saber como faço uma função similar a `map` sem usar o método.

Comment: Cara, não tá claro, para mim, exatamente o que tu precisas. Estás com algum problema? Alguma dificuldade?

Comment: Eu preciso percorrer um array e retornar um novo array modificado sem usar o map

Comment: Não tenho tempo agora para dar uma boa resposta, mas essa pergunta merece uma boa resposta. Antes de alguém responder uma besteira, a implementação que o AP apresentou para o método `Array.prototype.forEach()` é o que se chama de abordagem ingênua [aqui](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.foreach) está a especificação do algoritmo a ser implementado com o método `Array.prototype.forEach()` e [aqui](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.map) a especificação a ser implementada com  `Array.prototype.map()`

Comment: @AugustoVasques A pergunta parece boa, e foi bom destacar a especificação, porém o AP comentou algo que contradiz a pergunta. Ele perguntou como funciona, mas no comentário ele falou que quer fazer algo parecido com o `map`. Se fossemos responder, teríamos que detalhar o algoritmo de implementação, não acha? Fiquei um pouco na duvida...

Comment: @CmteCardeal, já havia visto o seu comentário, mas só agora o posso responder(um pouco atrasado). Eu compartilho da sua dúvida pois ao destacar a especificação, minha orientação teve o como objetivo pontuar a existência de um contexto ao qual os métodos citados estão inseridos e assim evitar que fossem formuladas respostas baseadas em analises incompletas ou impulsivas. Fico em dúvida em se poderia orientar sobre a forma ou meios utilizados para produzir a resposta, eu não acho que não, pois isso é pessoal e cada um dá o seu enfoque ao que acha mais relevante sendo livre a escolha de meios.

Comment: Deixando minha impressão pessoal, as duas respostas são excelentes com destaque para resposta aceita.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O [método `map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), além de chamar a função de *callback* para todos os elementos do array, também cria um novo array com o resultado dessas chamadas, e retorna esse array.

Sendo assim, bastaria percorrer o array, chamar a função e adicionar o resultado em outro array:

```js
function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
    // faz algo com o elemento e retorna o resultado (estou multiplicando por 2 só pra não retornar o mesmo número)
    return element * 2;
}

const conjuntoDados = [20, 15, 10, 5, 30];
const result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < conjuntoDados.length; i++) {
    // chama a função e adiciona o resultado em outro array
    result.push(callbackFn(conjuntoDados[i], i, conjuntoDados));
}
console.log(result);
```

Mas se você já tem a função de *callback* pronta, por que não fazer apenas `conjuntoDados.map(callbackFn)`?

Claro que daria para criar uma função, algo como:

```js
function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
    // faz algo com o elemento e retorna o resultado (estou multiplicando por 2 só pra não retornar o mesmo número)
    return element * 2;
}

function map(array, callbackFn, thisArg) {
    const result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        result.push(callbackFn.call(thisArg, array[i], i, array));
    }
    return result;
}

const conjuntoDados = [20, 15, 10, 5, 30];
const result = map(conjuntoDados, callbackFn, null);
console.log(result);
```

Modifiquei a chamada do *callback* para usar `call`, pois com isso posso setar o `thisArg`, que é basicamente o `this` que o *callback* enxergará (veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) para mais detalhes). Fiz assim porque o método `map` aceita este parâmetro (não ficou claro se você quer todas as funcionalidades que o método `map` nativo possui).

---

**Mas vale lembrar que, [conforme lembrado nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/556528/como-funciona-o-metodo-map-em-javascript#comment989286_556528), esta é uma implementação simplificada do método `map`, já que segundo a [especificação da linguagem](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.map), o algoritmo é um pouco mais complicado**.

Por exemplo, o método `map` verifica se foi de fato passada uma função como *callback* (fazer algo como `conjuntoDados.map('abc')` dá erro), além de ignorar índices que não existem no array.

Ou seja, para casos assim não daria o mesmo resultado:

```js
function callbackFn(element, index, array) {
    // faz algo com o elemento e retorna o resultado (estou multiplicando por 2 só pra não retornar o mesmo número)
    return element * 2;
}

const array = [];
array[2] = 42;
array.length = 6;
// somente o elemento da posição 2 está setado
console.log(array);

const result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    result.push(callbackFn(array[i], i, array));
}
console.log(result);
console.log(array.map(callbackFn));
```

Usando `map`, os elementos cujos índices não existem no array acabam sendo `undefined` (ver mais detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/468788/112052)), enquanto que se fizer o *loop*, eu acabo chamando o *callback* passando esses `undefined`, e ao fazer contas com `undefined`, o resultado acaba sendo `NaN` (claro que o resultado pode ser outro, dependendo do que o *callback* faz, mas de qualquer forma veja que há diferença).

Até daria para fazer algo como:

```js
const result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result[i] = callbackFn(array[i], i, array);
    }
}
result.length = array.length;
```

Assim, o resultado ficaria com a mesma quantidade de "elementos vazios", mas aí já acho que é "ginástica" demais para pouco ganho, e o melhor seria usar `map` mesmo.

Por fim, eu não entendi porque você quer criar uma função para substituir o `map`. Se não quer usar `map`, o *loop* simples me parece a melhor alternativa. Se for para jogar a lógica do *loop* em uma função, não vejo muito ganho, pois você trocou uma função nativa (o `map`) por uma função sua que ainda por cima não é tão completa (e se não for fazer tudo que o `map` faz, como validar se o argumento é uma função, ou se o caso do array com "espaços vazios" não se aplica, etc, ainda sim acho que um *loop* simples já resolve).

Comment: Obrigado a todos,precisava dessa função para substituir o map para entender como funciona "debaixo dos panos" a estrutura do map,para fins didáticos mesmo.

Comment: _"Se não quer usar map, o loop simples me parece a melhor alternativa"_ - Até complemento: _"Se não tem callback, o loop simples é melhor alternativa, quase que incondicionalmente, principalmente agora que viu que o map não é tão mágico assim"_ :D (para quem não entendeu a motivação, basta fazer benchmark - callback é um custo a mais, e usando map() você invariavelmente precisa de um, sendo que em loops convencionais dá para fazer as operações diretamente.)

Answer (score 4):

O método `map()`, da forma mais simples possível, é um método transformador. Seu papel é **criar um array novo** percorrendo os itens do array original e transformando-os no retorno da função que você definir.

**Exemplo:**

vamos supor que você tenha um array com alguns números `let numbers = [1, 2, 3];` e deseja que cada número deste array seja dobrado. Logo a abordagem seria:

```
let doubledNumbers = numbers.map(number => number * 2);
```

Novamente e muito importante: o `map()` cria um array novo. Não afetará em nada o array original.

### Foreach

O foreach, como você comentou no exemplo, tem outra finalidade: **percorrer o array**. Normalmente é utilizado quando você precisa executar uma ação para cada item, como chamar uma função.

### Re-implementação do `map()`:

Em sua pergunta, você disse que deseja fazer uma função correspondente ao map. Eu não entendi os motivos pra isso, uma vez que já existe o método no prototype do array. Mas a forma de fazer isso seria simplesmente receber um array e uma função transformadora, criar um array novo dentro desta função com base na função transformadora e retorná-lo.

Exemplo:

```js
    function map(originalArray, transformer) {
       let newArray = [];
       // Fazemos um loop para pegar os ítens do array
       for (let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
          // Chamamos a função transformadora passando o item e o índice atual e adicionamos a um novo array o valor que ela irá retornar
          newArray.push(transformer(originalArray[i], i));
       }
       
       return newArray;
    }

    // Como usar
    let numbers = [1, 2, 3];
    let doubledNumbers = map(numbers, number => number * 2);
    console.log(doubledNumbers);
    // [2, 4, 6]
```